# Output comes wrong when passed array of odd size and passes when passed array of even size. Where is the error?

Tags: c, output

Find Unique number where all other elements are duplicates.

Wrong Duplicate is given as output.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdbool.h>
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        printf("Enter number for array: \n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        int a[n];
        printf("Enter array: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if(a[i]==a[j]){
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if(flag==false){
                printf("%d is unique", a[i]);    ***should be 5 here***
                break;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

***5 should be the answer but its not***

*I tried many things but it did not change*

> OUTPUT HERE

```
Enter number for array: 
9 
Enter array: 
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
1 is unique
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails to determine the second 1 is a duplicate because it only checks elements after it, but its duplicate precedes it. You need a different algorithm.

Additionally, this is a “trick” question—there is a way to find the duplicate quickly in a single pass through the elements, instead of examining parts of the array repeatedly. You do not even need to store the elements in an array.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, 1 is flagged as unique because your program only checks elements after it.

Instead, you should run the inner `for loop` (loop with j) from position 0 and skip the i==j condition.

Second, `if(a[i]==a[j])` condition will benefit from an additional `break` statement. And the current `break` statement (after the print statement) should be removed, because it indicates that you are looking for the first unique number, not all of them.